# Variable name in string doesn't evaluate

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile. In my use case name of variable is stored in another variable. I am trying to evaluate it from function but it is not evaluating correctly.

In the code I want "devinit" to evaluate to UART_init. What is mistake in my code?

```
VAR=MYDEV
MYDEV_init=UART_init


define create_kernels_c
    echo GGGGG $(VAR)
    baseinit=$$(echo $(VAR)_init);
    $$(eval devinit=\$$baseinit);
    echo devinit $$devinit;
endef


all:
    @$(call create_kernels_c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable substitution twice and do not forget about `.ONESHELL:` (or append `;\<CR>` everywhere):

```
VAR=MYDEV
MYDEV_init=UART_init


define create_kernels_c
    echo GGGGG $(VAR)
    devinit=$($(VAR)_init)
    echo devinit $$devinit
endef


.ONESHELL:
all:
    @$(call create_kernels_c)
```